# How manage asynchronous using [displayWith] in autocomplete?

Tags: javascript, angular, asynchronous, angular-material, autocomplete

I have an autocomplete in my angular reactive form.
I want to display myObject.name but use myObject.id as value.

When the form is prefilled with existing values, I need to get myObject.name base on myObject.id which takes some time. So unfortunately, what is shown in the autocomplete is an id and not a name. I can't make it work.

I tried with observable but it looks like displayWith does not support it. How can I do that ?

**Typescript :**

```
    public displayWith(id: string): string {
    if (!id) {
        return '';
    }
    let freespinName = '';
    this.freespins$.pipe(takeUntilDestroyed(this.destroyRef)).subscribe(freespins => {
        const found = freespins.find((freespin: Freespin) => freespin.id === id);
        freespinName = found?.name || id;
    });

    return freespinName;
}
```

**HMTL :**

```
                     <mat-label>Freespin</mat-label>
                        <input type="text"
                               placeholder="Select a freespin"
                               matInput
                               formControlName="rewardId"
                               [matAutocomplete]="auto">
                        <mat-autocomplete requireSelection #auto="matAutocomplete"
                                          [displayWith]="displayWith.bind(this)">
                            <mat-option *ngFor="let freespin of filteredFreespins[i] | async"
                                        [value]="freespin.id">
                                {{freespin.name}}
                            </mat-option>
                        </mat-autocomplete>
                    </mat-form-field>
```

Comment: Are you saying you can retrieve the name but are not able to show the value in the form because it takes some time due to observable?

Comment: @collab-with-tushar-raj Yes, I added some console.log to see if the name was well retrieved, and it is. But it seems that the id is send first without waiting for the name. I made changes to send an Observable<string> instead of string but displayWith does not like it

Answer (score 0):

Please write this code on ngOnInit, we need to make the API call inside `displayWith`

> Note this is just pseudo code, but you can use this approach and try to fix your issue!

```
export class SomeComponent {

    nameIdMap = {};
    
    ngOnInit() {
    
        this.freespins$.pipe(takeUntilDestroyed(this.destroyRef)).subscribe(freespins => {
                this.nameIdMap = {};
                // creating this hashmap will ensure that you will immediately get the value of name
                freespins.forEach((freespin: any) => {
                    this.nameIdMap[freespin.id]=freespin.name;
                });
            });
    
    }
    
    diplayWith(id: string): string {
        return this.nameIdMap?.[id]?.name
    }

}
```

Comment: There must be another asynchronous issue as the autocomplete is now empty.

Comment: @Ryley38 Could you share a stackblitz with the code, I will check it?

Comment: I am not sure I will be able to provide a working stackblitz as this context involves too much files and too much dependencies to be reproduced

Answer (score 0):

If you are using angular 16+ you can use signals here

```
  private freespins = toSignal(this.freespins$);

displayFn(id: string) => string {
        return this.freespins()!.find((freespin) => freespin.name === id)?.name || '';
      }
```

you can also return function like this

```
  displayFn(): (freespins: any) => string {
    return (id: string) =>
      this.freespins()!.find((freespin) => freespin.name === id)?.name ||
      '';
  }
```

Also if `this.freespins$` is `BehaviourSubject` you can get the value without subscribing

```
private freeSpins$ = new BehaviorSubject(this.options);
  displayFn2(user: User): string {
    return (
      this.freeSpins$
        .getValue()!
        .find((freespin) => freespin.name === user.name)?.name || ''
    );
  }
```

the is another workaround you can do by returning a function and using async pipe

**in ts file**

```
displayFn3(spins: User[] | null): (user: User) => string {
    return (user: User) =>
      spins?.find((freespin) => freespin.name === user.name)?.name || '';
  }
```

**in HTML file**

```
<mat-autocomplete #auto="matAutocomplete" [displayWith]="displayFn3(freeSpins$ | async)">
    <mat-option *ngFor="let option of filteredOptions | async" [value]="option">{{option.name}}</mat-option>
  </mat-autocomplete>
```

check the example here
https://stackblitz.com/edit/bdx7mn?file=src%2Fexample%2Fautocomplete-display-example.ts,src%2Fexample%2Fautocomplete-display-example.html

Comment: thanks for your help. unfortunately, I a cannot use signals in the application.

Comment: I updated the answer and added another solution can help you

Answer (score 0):

Despite the fact that the answer from @Hussein AbdElaziz might work with signals, this problem was solved by changing the way freeSpins$ was retrieved in the component. Instead of calling it from the store, it was passed as an input from the parent, which resolved the asynchronous issue.

Comment: It'd be helpful to see a code snippet of exactly what you changed to resolve the issue.